# BadNeighbors - Topcoder puzzle

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

I'm learning Dynamic Programming, following the topcoder guide. I just solved the [BadNeighbors](http://community.topcoder.com/stat?c=problem_statement&pm=2402&rd=5009&rm=&cr=304031) puzzle. It passes all the test cases, but I don't have much experience, so I don't know if it's good.

> #### Puzzle Description:
>
> Each of the town's residents is willing to donate a certain amount, as specified in the `int[]` donations, which is listed in clockwise order around the well. However, nobody is willing to contribute to a fund to which his neighbor has also contributed. Next-door neighbors are always listed consecutively in donations, except that the first and last entries in donations are also for next-door neighbors. You must calculate and return the maximum amount of donations that can be collected.

```
def circle(lst):
    if len(lst) == 1:
        return lst[0]
    attempt_1 = _circle(lst, 0, len(lst)-1)
    attempt_2 = _circle(lst, 1, len(lst))
    return max(attempt_1, attempt_2)

def _circle(lst, start, end):
    prev, best = 0, 0
    for i in xrange(start, end):
        val = lst[i]
        current = val + best
        best = max(prev, best)
        prev = current
    return best
```

Edit: Check the comments of my selected answer for the full resolution.

Comment: You say this passes all the tests? Did you submit as well? I ask because the solution doesn't look like it will pass all tests but maybe this is just because I'm still eye balling it and haven't ran it

Comment: No, I just manually entered a bunch of cases and they all gave the correct response. I'm not sure how to submit. I was under the impression that once the competition was closed, there was no judge to submit it to. How would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code doesn't actually work for some tricky corner cases. Take e.g. `[1, 10, 1, 1, 9]`. It should be pretty obvious that `19` is the proper answer, but your code returns `11`. To build a working solution, let's leave the circularity out, you have already figured how to get the result for a circular array running twice over a linear array.

As ususal with DP we will consider the array incrementally, and in an array `dp[j]` we will store the value of the maximum donation from the first `j` neighbors *when the `j`-th neighbor is one of the donors*. It is relatively straightforward to see that then:

```
dp[j+1] = max(dp[:j]) + lst[j+1]
```

Note that the `max` excludes the value over `dp[j]`, as Python slices are right-exclusive.

We can turn this idea into code doing something like:

```
def mncs(lst):
    # MaximumNonContiguousSum
    dp = [0, 0]
    for item in lst:
        dp.append(max(dp[:-1]) + item)
    return max(dp)
```

This has a dreadful performance, \$O(n)\$ space and \$O(n^2)\$ time, because we are continuously rescanning the full `dp` array for the maximum. If we are only after the value of the maximum, and not the indices of the neighbors that produce it, we can minimize the overhead by keeping three numbers only, the previous maximum plus the last two entries:

```
def mncs(lst):
    dp = [0, 0, 0]
    for item in lst:
        m = max(dp[:-1])
        dp = [m, dp[-1], m + item]
    return max(dp)
```

Since we do constant work per entry, and keep a constant number of values as state, this solution uses \$O(1)\$ space and takes \$O(n)\$ time.

For completeness:

```
def mnccs(lst):
    # MaximumNonContiguousCircularSum
    return max(mncs(lst[1:]), mncs(lst[:-1]))
```

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the answer and pointing out the flaw in my code. I'm not 100% sure why we need to keep three variables though. Wouldn't it fix the problem to change the last line of _circle to return max(prev, best). It seems like the issue is an off by one error where my last prev value isn't compared to best.

Comment: That seems to work indeed...

Answer (score 0):

When you see this pattern:

```
for i in xrange(start, end):
    val = lst[i]
```

you can always immediately change it to:

```
for val in lst[start:end]:
```

In this case, you can drop `start` and `end` from the function arguments entirely, and just call it like this:

```
attempt_1 = _circle(lst[:-1])
attempt_2 = _circle(lst[1:])
```

And then do `for val in lst:`.

Comment: Doesn't that waste a lot of computation? According to python's time complexity guide, that's an O(k) operation. Would I convert it to a quick slicing immutable first? That I think that's still O(n). https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#list

Comment: If your lists are big enough that that's a concern (although, as always, profile first), there's [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice). The page you linked says there's a maximum of 40 elements, so I wouldn't expect slicing it twice to have any noticeable impact on anything.

Comment: Woah. itertools is amazing. Thank you for the link.